# How do I control space between bars?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am plotting bar chart using the following code:

```
heights1=c(5,5,4.5,4)
barplot(heights1, main="Language ", names.arg=c("Hindi R/W", "Speak" , "English 
R/W","Speak"), ylab=" level ", xlab="Language starting with mostly used",  
cex.names=0.8, col=c("darkblue","red"))
```

The output comes like this:

[image]

But What I want is that the "Hindi R/w" and "Speak" should combine **without any gap**, and then a space comes and then  "English R/w" and "Speak" should combine. How do I do this?

Answer (score 14):

You should add argument `space=` to your `barplot()` function, where numbers correspond to space before each bar.

```
heights1=c(5,5,4.5,4)    
barplot(heights1, main="Language ", names.arg=c("Hindi R/W", "Speak" , "English 
  R/W","Speak"), ylab=" level ", xlab="Language starting with mostly used",  
  cex.names=0.8, col=c("darkblue","red"),space=c(0.2,0,0.2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: This answers the question, but (to me) doesn't address the issue that the data from the OP are not currently in  a very useful format for the `barplot` function.

Answer (score 10):

Your life would be much easier if your data were properly formatted. The `barplot` function takes input of a `vector` or `matrix`. When the input is a `matrix`, R can use the `dimnames` to automatically label things for you.

Try this:

```
heights1 = c(5, 5, 4.5, 4)
barplot(t(matrix(heights1, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE, 
                 dimnames=list(c("Hindi", "English"), 
                               c("Read/Write", "Speak")))), 
        main="Language ", ylab="Level", 
        xlab="Language starting with mostly used", 
        col=c("darkblue", "red"), 
        beside=TRUE, ylim = c(0, 6), 
        legend.text = TRUE,
        args.legend = list(x = "topright"))
```

[image]

If the spacing between the two groups is too much, then the suggestion by @Didzis is appropriate here too. Add `space = c(0, .2)` to your `barplot` command, keeping in mind the details from the documentation:

> If `height` is a matrix and `beside` is `TRUE`, `space` may be specified by two numbers, where the first is the space between bars in the same group, and the second the space between the groups. If not given explicitly, it defaults to `c(0,1)` if height is a matrix and beside is `TRUE`, and to `0.2` otherwise.