# Add blank bar to traces in R Plotly bargraph

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly

I have the following data frame (dput(df)):

```
structure(list(lpc = c("Amory", "Appalachian", "Athens", "Blue Ridge", 
"Bolivar", "Bowling Green", "Bristol TN", "Bristol VA", "Brownsville", 
"Gallatin"), district = c("NMPPA", "ADPDA", "SDPDA", "SDPDA", 
"WDMA", "KPPA", "ADPDA", "ADPDA", "WDMA", "CDMA"), average = c(21679, 
185334, 66354, 131739, 45450, 137298, 162464, 79929, 21795, 94370
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L), .Names = c("lpc", 
"district", "average"))
```

I have a function I am using with Plotly that looks like this:

```
plot_district <- function (plot, dname) 
{
    if (dname == "ADPDA") {
        plot %>% filter(district == dname) %>% add_bars(x = ~lpc, 
            y = ~average, name = dname, type = "bar")
    }
    else {
        plot %>% filter(district == dname) %>% add_bars(x = ~lpc, 
            y = ~average, name = dname, type = "bar")
    }
}
```

With this function (plot_district), and this data frame (df), I am making the following plot with the help of dplyr:

```
df %>%
  arrange(district, average, lpc) %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_fun(plot_district, 'ADPDA') %>%
  add_fun(plot_district, 'CDMA') %>%
  add_fun(plot_district, 'KPPA') %>%
  add_fun(plot_district, 'NMPPA') %>%
  add_fun(plot_district, 'SDPDA') %>%
  add_fun(plot_district, 'WDMA') %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(categoryorder = 'array', categoryarray = 'average'))
```

Visual:
[image: result]

However, I would like to add 1 blank bar of data to each of my traces EXCEPT the first trace so that it will result in a visual gap between each of my traces on the graph. I have tried altering my function by adding an rbind('') like so:

```
plot_district <- function (plot, dname) 
    {
        if (dname == "ADPDA") {
            #this will always be the first trace and it doesn't need space
            plot %>% filter(district == dname) %>% add_bars(x = ~lpc, 
                y = ~average, name = dname, type = "bar")
        }
        else {
            #this will be every other trace and they will need space after them
            #added the rbind() below
            plot %>% filter(district == dname) %>% rbind('') %>% add_bars(x = ~lpc, 
                y = ~average, name = dname, type = "bar")
        }
    }
```

This allows me to run the following code without error:

```
df %>% filter(district == 'CDMA') %>% rbind('') %>% plot_ly(x = ~lpc, y = ~average, name = 'CDMA', type = 'bar')
```

but as soon as I run the code for the whole graph it gives me the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "list"
```

How can I add a blank bar to each trace?

Comment: Instead of adding faux data between the bars, you might be better off adding space in your plotly chart like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932708/how-do-i-control-space-between-bars  where they went in the opposite direction (removing space) just add some value to the first in the pair (8, 8) and see what happens

Comment: It looks like they used 'space' in that question. However, space is not a plotly attribute. I tried it and got a warning.